# Is it possible to replay django-simple-history up to a specific ID to restore a delete database?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

The situation is:

I developped a webapp using django (and especially "django-simple-history").
I have a postgres database "db01" with a history model "db01_history" which is generated/filled using "django-simple-history".
I accidentally deleted everything from "db01"and, sadly, I don't have any db backup.

My question is:
Is there some way to replay all historical records "db01_history" (up to a specific ID) onto original database "db01" ?
(In other words, is there a way to restore a db using its historical model up to a specific date/ID ?)

Giving `db0_history -> db01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, django-simple-history keeps using your own model's field names and types (but does not keep some constraints).

The difference is that there are multiple historical objects for each of your deleted objects. If you use Django default primary key (`id`) it would be easy for you to group your tables by `id` and use the latest record as of `history_date` (the time of recorded history).

An exception is that if you use more direct database operations like `update`s or `bulk_create`s from model managers you don't have their histories.

So you can just configure your project to use a copy of the historical database only having the latest record for each object and then try to do `python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json` and then revert the database settings to the new database you like and do `python manage.py loaddata dump.json`.

To be concise, yes you may have all your data in your historical database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! I was able to extract the historical data using the dumpdata command, then I filtered the data in the json file to reimport lost data !